# How to implement selection

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make my very first XNA game and I cannot figure out how to implement the following:
I have a list of objects of different types, they are loaded and drawn. By clicking on one of that objects I need to create a new object of the same type and add this new object to another list.
I've tried the following code and I can add as many objects as I want to a new list, but only if I click on the zeroth object.(all of them have a type of the zeroth object). When I click on the other objects nothing happens. How to make it work?

```
for (int i = 0; i < initialPlanets.Count; i++)
{
    MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    if (initialPlanets[i].CollisionRectangle.Contains(
    mouse.X, mouse.Y) &&
    mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released &&
    previousButtonState == ButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        userPlanetSequence.Add(new Planet(
        initialPlanets[i].Type, 
        GetPlanetSprite(initialPlanets[i].Type),
        new Vector2(100 * (i + 1), 100)));
    }
    previousButtonState = mouse.LeftButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call this on a click event.

You are polling the mouse state every time you go through the loop.The first time you go through it (on object zero) you set `previousButtonState = mouse.LeftButton` so subsequent loops' if statement will always be false.

I can't give a complete example without knowing how you set the `previousButtonState` initially, but a step in the right direction will be putting `MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState()` outside the loop so you get it only once.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Both MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState() and previousButtonState = mouse.LeftButton should be outside the loop.

Comment: @Ksenia Glad I could help. If you feel it was helpful, an upvote and a checkmark could signal other members of the community that it might be helpful to them too.